# Notification with sound although phone is muted

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am creating a notification with Android's NotificationManager.

Is it possible to 'override' the phone's volume (mute) settings in such a way, that the notification's sound is ALWAYS played?

The reason I need this is the following:
The notification is so important, that vibration alone may not be enough. The user MUST be alerted. So a sound shall be played, even if the phone is muted or the volume is very low.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes it is possible,

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
Uri notification = null;
notification = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, notification);
        // mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, notification);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        // mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mMediaPlayer.start();

            }

        });
```

Comment: How does this code change the volume/mute mode of the phone? Is it done implicitly? Or am I just blind? ;-)

Comment: mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM); this line changes the audio type

Answer (score 4):

You can change RINGING mode like this from silent to normal

```
AudioManager mobilemode = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);


        // Turn on all sound

        // turn on sound, enable notifications
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
        //notifications
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
        //alarm
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
        //ringer
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        //media
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);


        // Turn off all sound

        // turn off sound, disable notifications
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
        //notifications
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
        //alarm
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
        //ringer
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
        //media
        mobilemode.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

**FOR YOUR CASE YOU CAN TRY SOMETHING LIKE THIS**

```
int previousNotificationVolume =mobilemode.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

        mobilemode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,mobilemode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);

        // Play notification sound



        // Set notification sound to its previous 

        mobilemode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,previousNotificationVolume, 0);
```

Comment: Looks promising. Is there a sleek way to bring the settings back to their initial values AFTER the notification sound has been played? E.g. without using a fixed timer or something?

Comment: I have given you a general purpose solution. But your concern is only about notification sound right?

Comment: Yes. The volume shall be turned on while the notification sound is being played. After that the settings should return to their initial values (e.g. the phone is muted again). So your code does help a lot. But I would need a way to call 'setStreamMute' after the notification sound is over...

Comment: previousNotificationVolume is for set it to its previous state. Because it may possible that the notification volume is set to 1 very low not mute.So it must be set to 1 after your notification played. That's why I don't set it to mute mode.