# How to play custom notification sound, when phone is muted?

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications

I would like to play sound using NotificationCompat.Builder when phone is muted.
I tried to do that using AudioManager, but I found no solution to my problem. When phone isn't muted everything works fine. Anyone has some tips how to make it?

Comment: [check this once ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353361/notification-with-sound-although-phone-is-muted)hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I saw this question, but i really didn't liked solution with media player, and the second one wasn't working for me.