# OneSignal Cordova SDK handleNotificationRecieved not fired

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal Cordova SDK to push alarms to the phones of my school paramedics. Everything is working fine but if phone is muted, no notification-sound is beeing played.

So i need to inject a function when Push is received, that checks if phone is muted and if so plays an alarm.

I thought i can inject function in "handleNotificationReceived" but it's never fired:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
window.plugins.OneSignal
.startInit("MY-APP-ID")    
.inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
        .handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
        window.androidVolume.getNotification(oldsuc,olderr);
        window.androidVolume.setNotification(100, false, volsuc);
        console.log('Empfange Alarm: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
      })
        .endInit();
    }, false);
    function oldsuc(r){
        console.log('Altes Volumen' + r);
        localStorage.oldvol = r;
    }
    function olderr(){
        console.log('Konnte Volumen nicht abfragen');
    }
    function volsuc(r){
        vol = r;
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.androidVolume.setNotification(localStorage.oldvol, false);
        }, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification with sound although phone is muted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353361/notification-with-sound-although-phone-is-muted)

Comment: Don't know how to implement this cause .handleNotificationReceived is never fired